# How do I trick my internet browser that I'm using 32bit Operating System even it's a 64bit application

Tags: operating-system

Some websites detect my operating system architecture automatically and I don't know how they get the value (eg. 32-bit / 64-bit OS). So they can use the value for the following case:

Example of the case:

If I want to download something for Example 'Google Chrome', the Google Chrome Download Page thinks that I'm using 64bit operating system and thus it downloads 'ChromeStandalone64.exe for me. If I want to download the 32bit, I need to be on the 32bit OS OR I need to click on the other platform. This is just a use case example.

So in general, my question is how do I trick the browser (using any scripting language) that I use 32bit OS ? I know there is a chrome plugin that disguises the Chrome browser as different browser like Safari, Internet explorer. it works. but what about tricking the browser as 64bit or 32bit?

Edit: Please do not give me the answer how to download a Google Chrome. I just gave an example of the case.

Comment: This question is off-topic here as it is not related to programming in any way. Any website that offers downloads for multiple platforms has an option to choose the platform to download for.

Comment: And there is no veto power to downvote. Each user has equal right and power to downvote as he or she sees fit. [No explanation mandated](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/7223/downvoting-a-question-should-require-a-comment-upvote-of-a-comment)

Comment: Just ignore the example of Google Chrome and my main question is how do I trick my browser that I use 32 bit OS in certain websites ?

Comment: I have edited my question. That's it.

Comment: why do you need this?

Comment: @bolov For fun!!

Comment: I update my question again.

Comment: This question related to programming. Don't judge the book by its cover.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Google Chrome, you could try clicking on "Other Platforms" near the bottom of the https://www.google.com/chrome/ page, then choose the 32-bit version. If you install and browse with the 32-bit version, you may automatically get offered 32-bit versions of other software.

Another option would be to edit your user agent string. (Updated with more details:) The user agent string is the text that your browser sends to the web server to identify itself, e.g., "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.186 Safari/537.36". On Chrome, it's a little convoluted to change, but you can find instructions at: http://technipages.com/google-chrome-change-user-agent-string . This may help, but not if the web servers use some other method to identify your machine as 64-bit.

Comment: What do you mean by user agent string in the case of Google Chrome Browser ? I'm using 64 bit Chrome.

Comment: The user agent string is the text that your browser sends to the web server to identify itself, e.g., "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.186 Safari/537.36". On Chrome, it's a little convoluted to change, but you can find instructions here: https://www.technipages.com/google-chrome-change-user-agent-string . This may help, but not if the web servers use some other method to identify your machine as 64-bit.

Comment: I accepted this answer because you mention about 'user agent string'. even that's the small answer how things are done. it's useful.

Comment: But, actually I know how to download Google Chrome 32 bit or 64 bit.

Comment: If you could please put your answer from your comment so that other people can see. I use the extension to put it as old internet explorer and the browser can be tricked as 32bit. Thank you so much.

Comment: Ok, I copied it into the answer. Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 0):

Websites can use either the User-Agent string which you can change with a browser extension, or the Javascript `window.navigator.platform` value which I don't believe an extension can change.

There is a "Download for other platforms" link at the bottom of the page that lets you download Chrome for 32-bit Windows:

[image]

Comment: Hai, my question is more about how do I trick the browser that I have 32-bit operating system ? I think I can do this with Google how to download Google Chrome. I just gave an example of the case.

Comment: So it is impossible to change that "window.navigator.platform"

Comment: I know how to download Google Chrome 32 bit and 64 bit

Comment: This post doesn't answer my question